# st_buffer "missing" part of multipolygon using sf in R

Tags: r, r-sf, arcpullr

I am using the `sf` package in R along with the `arcpullr` package to pull in data from an ArcGIS REST service and work with it as an `sf` object. I have run into an issue with a MULTIPOLYGON where `sf` is only buffering a part of the MULTIPOLYGON (i.e., it buffers one polygon but only tiny slivers of the other). I have not been able to replicate the problem when buffering the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512431/how-to-separate-a-multipolygon-geometry-into-several-polygons-objects-after-perf).

Here is an MRE (sorry, you'll have to install arcpullr if you don't have it).

```r
# install.packages("arcpullr")
library(arcpullr)
library(sf) # redundant since loaded with arcpullr, but here for brevity
library(ggplot2)

tax_parcel_url <- paste0(
  "https://mapservices.legis.wisconsin.gov/arcgis/rest/services/", 
  "WLIP/Parcels/FeatureServer/0"
)
parcel <- 
  get_spatial_layer(tax_parcel_url, where = "PARCELID = 'HA-11'") %>%
  st_transform(crs = 3071)
parcel_buffer <- st_buffer(parcel, dist = 10)

# map of parcel
ggplot(data = parcel) + geom_sf() # this is correct

# map of parcel and buffer - buffer "misses" part of multipolygon
ggplot(data = parcel_buffer) + 
  geom_sf(color = "blue") + 
  geom_sf(data = parcel, color = "red", alpha = 0.3) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hi! I just want to point out that I get a "Timeout was reached" error when running get_spatial_layer. Can you try to rerun the code? Or maybe share the object in other ways?

Comment: Thanks @agila. Mine runs in 0.41 seconds. It's possible there was a server issue when you ran it. Try it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe in `st_make_valid` to `parcel`, which will correct the geometry with the `sf` object (i.e., make the geometry valid). This will allow for the buffer to plot correctly on all parts of the multipolygon.

```
library(arcpullr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

parcel <-
  arcpullr::get_spatial_layer(tax_parcel_url, where = "PARCELID = 'HA-11'") %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = 3071) %>%
  sf::st_make_valid()

parcel_buffer <- sf::st_buffer(parcel, dist = 10)

ggplot(data = parcel_buffer) +
  geom_sf(color = "blue") +
  geom_sf(data = parcel,
          color = "red",
          alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

Mapview

You can see that the buffer is clear in `mapview` as well.

```
library(mapview)

mapview::mapview(parcel_buffer) + mapview::mapview(parcel)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Works perfectly!